# How to parse documents with or without xml namespaces?

Tags: linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have some XML files to parse, some of them are like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ab:rootNode xmlns:ab="http://www.uri.com">
    <ab:nodeDate>...</ab:nodeDate>
</ab:rootNode>
```

and other of them are without namespace:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootNode>
    <nodeDate>...</nodeDate>
</node>
```

In LINQ to XML, I should to precise the namespace otherwise it don't fine any nodes.
How to manage namespaces? Do I test if `xmlns:ab="http://www.uri.com"` exist in the `rootNode` element? and if it exists I create a `XNamespace` and add it to the name element like this (pseudo code):

```cs
XNamespace ab = "http://www.uri.com";
string prefixe = String.Empty;

if (XmlNamespaceExists(ab , "rootNode")
{
   prefixe = ab;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
var dates = doc.Descendants(ns + "nodeDate");
```

I believe that should work whether or not namespaces are used - it just ends up finding every `nodeDate` element with the same namespace as the root element.